# Getting the roles of a user in wso2

Tags: java, jsp, wso2

I've created users and assigned them different roles using wso2im. Using these I managed to restrict access to a .jsp file so roles seem to be working right.

The problem lies when I need to display different things to different roles within the same JSP (For instance, role AAA can do xxx and yyy, role BBB can do zzz), I'm trying to check for roles using request.isUserInRole("role") but it always returns null, both when trying from the .jsp itself and the servlet that handles authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get it to work. Getting the roles with the servlet and storing them in a cookie. Neither safe nor pretty but does the job:

```html
package foo;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HttpTransportProperties;
import org.apache.axis2.client.Options;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants;

import org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String basicAuthUserID = "admin";
    private final String basicAuthPassword = "admin";
    private final String serverUrl = "https://localhost:9444/services/";
    private RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub stub = null;


    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 
        // get request parameters for userID and password
        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
          
        try {
   if(authenticate(user,pwd)){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
       session.setAttribute("user", user);
       //setting session to expiry in 30 mins
       session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60);
       Cookie userName = new Cookie("user", user);
       userName.setMaxAge(30*60);
    
    String[] roles = getRoleListOfUser(user);
    String rolesTodos = null;
    for (String s: roles){
     if (!s.equals("Internal/everyone")) {
      if (rolesTodos == null){
       rolesTodos = s;
      } else {
       //System.out.println("Rol: " + s);
       rolesTodos = rolesTodos + "," + s;
      }
     }
    }
    
    //System.out.println("Roles: " + rolesTodos);
       Cookie rolesCookie = new Cookie("roles", rolesTodos);
    rolesCookie.setMaxAge(30*60);
        
       response.addCookie(userName);
       response.addCookie(rolesCookie);
       response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
   }else{
       RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
       PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
       out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
       rd.include(request, response);
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 
    }
    
    private boolean authenticate(String userName, Object credential) throws Exception {
        if (!(credential instanceof String)) {
            throw new Exception("Unsupported type of password");
        }
        try {
         if(stub == null) {
             stub = new RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub(null, serverUrl
                     + "RemoteUserStoreManagerService");
             HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
                basicAuth.setUsername(basicAuthUserID);
                basicAuth.setPassword(basicAuthPassword);
                basicAuth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);

                final Options clientOptions = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
                clientOptions.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuth);
                stub._getServiceClient().setOptions(clientOptions);

         }
            return stub.authenticate(userName, (String) credential);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handleException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    private String[] handleException(String msg, Exception e) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + e);
        throw new Exception(msg, e);
    }
    
    public String[] getRoleListOfUser(String userName) throws Exception {
        try {
            return stub.getRoleListOfUser(userName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```